# How to alias this in JavaScript 2015 (EcmaScript 6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

In EcmaScript 5, we can alias `this` as `var ctrl = this` as shown in following snippet.

```
// EcmaScript 5
function BookController {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.books = [];

    ctrl.getBook = getBook;

    function getBook(index) {
        return ctrl.books[index];
    }
}
```

Equivalent `BookController` in ES6 using `class`. I had a scenario in which `getBook` is called with `this` other than `BookController`. In `getBook` function, I want to make sure the context is always `BookController` so I want to alias `this` of `BookController` in ES6.

```
// EcmaScript 6
class BookController {

    constructor() {
        this.books = [];
    }

    getBook(index) {
        return this.books[index];
    }
}
```

**How to alias `this` in JavaScript 2015 (EcmaScript 6)?**

Comment: Although your question does make sense, it is usually up to the caller to ensure that functions are called in a proper context. Otherwise, you cannot use prototype inheritance the way it was designed.

Comment: This behavior is result of a closure, not an alias.

Comment: I wished to not populate my page with `this`, so `function references() {  countrefs++;function refs() {this.refs = [];this.citeRef = (idx) => { return(this.refs[idx] = {});};return this.refs;}return new refs();}` and to use `export default function Dependency() {const dependen = references().citeRef(countrefs);return dependen}` might work. Would like to lose that `()` as well, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Equivalent `BookController` in ES6 using class.

No, it's not equivalent, it's markedly different. Your `class` example is essentially equivalent to this ES5:

```
function BookController {
    this.books = [];
}
BookController.prototype.getBook = function getBook(index) {
    return this.books[index];
};
```

Note that `getBook` is defined on the prototype that will be assigned to instances when you use `new BookController`. But that's not what your first example does. Your first example assigns a different `getBook` to each instance, as an "own" (not inherited) property.

> In `getBook` function, I want to make sure the context is always `BookController` so I want to alias `this` of `BookController` in ES6.

It's not an alias, it's a reference. You do it much the same way (in the constructor), but without the need of a variable:

```
// EcmaScript 6
class BookController {

    constructor() {
        this.books = [];
        this.getBook = index => {
            return this.books[index];
        };
    }
}
```

Because that's an arrow function, it closes over `this`.

Example:

```js
// EcmaScript 6
class BookController {

  constructor() {
    this.books = [];
    this.getBook = index => {
      return this.books[index];
    };
  }
}

let c1 = new BookController();
c1.books.push("The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy");
let f1 = c1.getBook;

let c2 = new BookController();
c2.books.push("Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?");
let f2 = c2.getBook;

console.log(f1(0));
console.log(f2(0));
```

Note, though, that without a specific reason to do that, the normal thing is to leave management of `this` to the caller.

Comment: The thing to take home from this is that OP's assertion *"Equivalent BookController in ES6 using class"* wasn't quite right. They are not equivalent because the first example assigns the methods in constructor, while the second uses `prototype` behind the scenes.

Comment: `this.getBook = this.getBook.bind(this);` --- just to keep code clear and separate implementation.

Comment: @zerkms: That is another option, yes. I don't think it's clearer, though, to define a function on the prototype that you're actually only going to use as an "own", bound function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree that it's subjective, but when number of functions grows - I think it's clearer to declare them in a "native" way and then just rebound in constructor.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank You :) #TIL